# .slideToggle(); function Hides wrong element when clicked twice

Tags: jquery

For the life of me I have no idea why this is happening. I have a button what when clicked hides a  and when clicked again it shows the same

The problem is that when you scroll to the next page and repeat the process the button itself disappears. Leaving you with no way to see or get back to the content that is hidden.

Is there something I am doing wrong or am I approaching this the wrong way?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".more").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>

<button id="btn_text" class="button"> Show / Hide Property Details</button>
        <div id="example" class="more">
            <! -- lots of stuff -->
        </div>
```

Comment: what you mean by `scroll to the next page`?

Comment: The code is used to hide / show details of a property. There are multiple properties and a button that scrolls to the next listing.

Comment: Maybe what you need/mean is: `$(this).next(".more").slideToggle();`. And beware IDs must be unique on document context, just a side note

Comment: This question gets 2 upvotes, really?! What's wrong with you SO?

Comment: seems like you haven't posted all of your JS and HTML code. From the code you posted above it is impossible to hide the button.

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks, That made a difference for sure, but now the element hides on the third click, and not the second. Is there a way to reset the function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/johannesMt/69fu82xq/

I think you should put your `JS` code below `HTML` then everything it will work.
Something like this:

First HTML:

```
<button id="btn_text" class="button"> Show / Hide Property Details</button>
        <div id="example" class="more">
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne labitur quaestio persecuti eum, et mea feugiat tibique. Et usu doctus senserit. Epicurei laboramus vim id, purto disputationi ex nam, pro iisque placerat at. Pri habeo iriure cu, pericula petentium cu mel.
            </p>
        </div>
```

and then put js:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".more").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: thanks for the Fiddle [link[(https://jsfiddle.net/johannesMt/69fu82xq/) it works just like I have it on the site. however even if I place to code under the HTML the <button> element still hides if I click on it more than once. 

Any thoughts?

Comment: First remove `jQuery.noConflict();` ,  try to check another functions with button's click, for example use `css('background-color', 'red')` or something like that instead of `.slideToggle()`. Then see what happens.

Comment: I am not sure how to use the `css('background-color', 'red')` do I just replace the `.slideToggle()` with it?

Comment: The color changes and stays changed on all pages,

Comment: I think what needs to happen is the code needs to reset once a user goes to another page / link. Is this a possibility?

Comment: it means the `click` reach selector, could you update your code and post css code of `.more` element?

Comment: thanks for the help so far, 

the css for .more is ` .more{
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255,0.9);
  font-size:80%;
  }`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".more").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>`

where would the `click` selector go?

Comment: your jquery seems to be old, try this: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js or this 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js or upper versions.

Comment: Ugh, Same results :(

Comment: then try use id `example` insead of `more` class, you might have the same class name for other elements, whereas id's are unique `$("#example").slideToggle();`

Comment: I tried Changing the id and the class. no luck. 

when the page loads the first time the .more dive is visible. when you click on the button it hides the div. when you then click on the button again the div shows. 

the kicker is that when the next property loads, and you click the button the div hides, and then if you click the button again the button hides. 

could the button be the conflict?

Comment: what is the next property that loads later?

Comment: a bunch of PHP for sliders and to pull content from meta fields in WP

Comment: then it should cause the problem, try to write code again from the beginning, sometimes it helps. Good luck.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I wish I could just reset the function when the page reloads or the next listing is loaded.

Comment: wait, is the loading of a new content reloading the page?

Comment: no, all the images are pre-loaded and the page appears to refresh.  but its really just the next listing that is revealed 

You can tell me I am being an idiot... I kinda feel like one ;)

Comment: I guess page refresh is the source of issue, try to load content with ajax then the content wll be loaded without refreshing the page and the code will work

Comment: I inherited this WordPress website, is there anyway to see if there is a reload problem? or is there anyway to force a reload of this code? or do a reset?

Comment: no idea, but you can search how to trigger reload event with js/jquery.

Comment: Yup the page does not actually reload or refresh, instead the next item, in this case another property and description is revealed. I added the location.reload(); function and this takes me back to the original listing. 

so what is happening is that the `<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".more").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>` is not firing more than once, if the next listing is revealed the code somehow stops working as intended.